# OpenLayers 3 draw path with coordinates

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I'm trying to use the Geolocation service of Openlayers 3 to map the users movement and collect coordinates based on distance and then either provide a measurement or a polygon shape that will be displayed on the map.

I've done quite a bit of research and haven't found anything that would even really get me started toward my end goal.  Is this possible with OpenLayers 3? Is there something already built in that I can use or would i have to build this from scratch using OpenLayers 3 components.

The code I currently have just turns OpenLayers location services on through the browser and tracks the location.

```
   new ol.Geolocation({
                projection: mapObj.getView().getProjection(),
                tracking: true,
                trackingOptions: {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            })
                .on('change', function () {
                    geoLocationPosition = this.getPosition();
                    geoLocationHeading = this.getHeading() || 0;


             mapObj.getView().setCenter(geoLocationPosition);
                    var trackerStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: '#383838',
                            width: 1
                        }),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#319FD3'
                        })
                    });
                    geoLocationCircle.setStyle(trackerStyle);
                    geoLocationCircle.setGeometry(
                        new ol.geom.Circle(geoLocationPosition, 5)
                    );


                })



            };
```

Any help in guiding me in the right direction is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) interaction GeolocationDraw that combines a geolocation with a draw interaction to track the location.
https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/mobile/map.interaction.geolocationdraw.html

Here is the doc: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.interaction.GeolocationDraw.html

Comment: Thank you!!  Super cool library...it seems that it is "all or nothing" ...so I get maybe 5 tools that I will use and 20 that I wont.  Have you noticed if loading this creates overhead to slow down the application?

Comment: You can use the library as ES2015 modules but if you want to use it as a lib in a web page you'll have to edit the gulpfile.js to include just what you want (modify the src in the js or in the extrajs task). Anyway the .min.js is just 252ko.

Comment: The lib is no more  "all or nothing": I've published a new version of openlayers-ext package to npm to use ol-ext with a browser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers-ext). It includes a ./lib directory that contains individual js files thus you can choose witch one to include in your projects. You can also create the lib with the `gulp lib` command.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm a little confused...it seems when I click the "github.com" link in openlayers-ext I'm directed to ol-ext GIT and I don't see the "node_modules/openlayers-ext/lib".  Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Comment: There is only one project: ol-ext but 2 npm packages. The lib is created on the flow when publishing openlayers-ext to npm, so you'll have to use the `npm install openlayers-ext` command to get it.

Comment: You also can run `gulp lib` to create the lib in the ol-ext project.

Comment: I've added the lib as a zip file in the github release https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/releases/tag/v2.0.1 :)